# Cannot unregister UpdatePanel with ID 'UpdatePanel1' since it was not registered with the ScriptManager

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here is my code:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
        ScriptManager sm = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page);
        MethodInfo m = (
        from methods in typeof(ScriptManager).GetMethods(
            BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance
            )
        where methods.Name.Equals("System.Web.UI.IScriptManagerInternal.RegisterUpdatePanel")
        select methods).First<MethodInfo>();

        m.Invoke(sm, new object[] { updatePanel});
        base.OnInit(e);
}
```

aspx file:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" 
OnUnload="UpdatePanel_Unload"></asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Now it shows the error:

> 'ASP.v4_inbox_new_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'UpdatePanel_Unload' and no extension method 'UpdatePanel_Unload' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.v4_inbox_new_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> The name 'updatePanel' does not exist in the current context

Comment: I thinks its telling you that `UpdatePanel_Unload` function is not present in the code behind file.

Comment: where?,  Its full source code, and it is placed in master file: asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">   </asp:ScriptManager>

Answer (score 0):

> 'ASP.v4_inbox_new_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'UpdatePanel_Unload' and no extension method 'UpdatePanel_Unload' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.v4_inbox_new_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

This is a result of your markup:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" OnUnload="UpdatePanel_Unload"></asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Particularly, `OnUnload="UpdatePanel_Unload"` is wrong since `UpdatePanel_Unload` does not exist in your code.

> The name 'updatePanel' does not exist in the current context E:\selva\19-09-2015\AlertID4\UI\V4\Inbox_new.aspx.cs

This is a result of your code:

```
m.Invoke(sm, new object[] { updatePanel});
```

`updatePanel` is not defined anywhere.

Comment: for that, what i should i do, i m new to c# .. help me, please

Comment: my main error is, Cannot unregister UpdatePanel with ID 'UpdatePanel1' since it was not registered with the ScriptManager. for that only i added above code.

Comment: I really don't understand that comment. I don't know what does it mean to *unregister* in this context. My answer explains your error messages - is my explanation clear to you?

Comment: no.. yar.. forgot all the code,  actually i got error like this, Cannot unregister UpdatePanel with ID 'UpdatePanel1' since it was not registered with the ScriptManager ..